# should matchMedia orientation become Landscape when I enter data into a form field?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, orientation-changes, matchmedia

On my S3 both Chrome and Firefox fire a matchMedia event saying I'm in landscape mode when I'm in portrait mode and touch a data entry field to enter data.  On my iPad, this does not happen.  It is certainly undesirable to announce orientation has changed when it hasn't - is this spurious landscape  orientation event per spec?    home.comcast.net/~tommoran4/bug.htm demonstrates the problem.